# How can I split a window so that the cursor ends up in the right / lower window?

Tags: window, window-splitting

The functions I have found for splitting windows are `(split-window-right)` and `(split-window-below)`. When these are evaluated the cursor ends up in the right window in the case of `(split-window-right)`or the upper window in the case of `(split-window-below)`.

I want to have functions that split a window and puts the cursor in the right or lower window.

I wrote the following myself, but it unfortunately does not move the cursor as I expected. Instead it just behaves as if `(split-window-right)` was called by itself.

```lisp
(defun olav-split-window-left ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (windmove-right))
```

Comment: Starting from a single window and executing this function with `M-x olav-split-window-left`, it works for me as expected: it splits the window into two side-by-side windows and the window on the right is selected.

Comment: Interesting. It turns out that the function works on non-configured Emacs, but not on my configuration which is weird considering it is sub 100 loc that I just started writing today. Regardless Fran's solution worked for me.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a duplicate. We have many questions with tag `window-splitting` (and other window tags). I'm guessing many are similar or essentially the same. Would someone like to take a look and maybe consolidate as a community question or two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(defun olav-split-window-left ()
  (interactive)
  (select-window (split-window-right)))
```