# Split window and move cursor to new window with predefined Emacs command/function

Tags: window-splitting, selected-window

I can split windows with `C-x 2` (`split-window-below`) or `C-x 3` (`split-window-right`). But the cursor does not move to the new window.

When I split I need to have the cursor in the new window. Is there a *predefined* Emacs command that does this?

I am aware about that there are some solutions with self written functions.

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/59594/12999

https://stackoverflow.com/q/26603438/4865723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no predefined function for that functionality (in Emacs 28).

Answer (score 2):

Nope. What’s wrong with taking one that you’ve found and binding it to a key?